# form_for with slim does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, slim-lang

I am using rails 4.0.2 with ruby 1.9.3. When I use rails scaffold generator like this `rails g scaffold Person name:string` everything works correctly. But i want to use Slim language for templating, so i added `gem 'slim'` to my `Gemfile`. Then changed the file `_form.html.erb` to this:

```
- form_for(@person) do |f|
  .field
    == f.label :name
    == f.text_field :name

  .actions
    == f.submit
```

changed the name to `_form.html.slim`. But now my form and anything else inside is not rendered at all. Meanwhile if i add  something else outside of the `form_for`, they work. What's the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be the following. Note that you need to render the form, since form is a html element.

```
= form_for(@person) do |f|
  .field
    == f.label :name
    == f.text_field :name

  .actions
    == f.submit
```